# Что почитать по Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, книги

Подскажите, что почитать по Spring Framework? Интересует именно ПРАКТИЧЕСКОЕ руководство со множеством примеров, которые можно набрать и прощупать (язык русский/английский).

Comment: щас попытаюсь ответить на целую пачку аналогичных вопросов:

"литературу, мануалы, faq, tutorial'ы"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

["Spring in Action", 2 ed.](http://www.amazon.com/Spring-Action-Craig-Walls/dp/1933988134/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1315771228&sr=8-1) - по второму спрингу, достаточно известная и хорошая книга. 3-е издание, посвященное 3-й версии, на мой взгляд, не особо - объем полезного текста уменьшился. Ревьюеры на амазоне отмечают то же самое. Поэтому в свое время заказал ["Spring Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach"](http://www.amazon.com/Spring-Recipes-Problem-Solution-Gary-Mak/dp/1430224991/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1315771243&sr=8-1) - очень большая, много примеров (собственно, в этом и суть книги). Понравилась (хотя лично для меня были минусом примеры интеграции Spring Web Flow с JSF 1.2, когда уже 2.0 в ходу).

Answer (score 5):

Вот очень неплохой [ресурс.](http://www.springbyexample.org/)

Comment: Буду рад, если кому пригодится.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы посоветовал [официальную документацию](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html).
Все ясно и по полочкам.

Answer (score 3):

Официальную документацию лучше смотреть всегда текущую http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/

Comment: Никак не пойму, почему на самом сайте spring.io не найти ссылку именно на этот гайд. Не туда смотрю?