# Что почитать по java

Tags: книги, java-ee

Здравствуйте! 
Сначала небольшая предыстория. Я занимаюсь программированием полтора года. Конечно я до сих пор намного ближе к новичку чем к профи, но все-таки кое что уже знаю. Начинал изучение с С++ по книге Стивена Праты. Вот по этой:
http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7979735/
Она по-моему просто великолепна для начинающих, основы там разжеваны. Потом перешел на java. Благо синтаксис родственный, а основы едины вообще почти для всех языков. Java изучал по книге Шилдта: Java 7, правда дошел пока только до половины. Но по крайней мере отлично представляю в чем отличия final, finally, и finalize и тому подобные вещи. В общем в программировании в целом и в java в частности уже не новичок. Но очень хочется повысить свой уровень. Решил продолжать изучение по книге Шилдта, а после нее проштудировать Блоха Effective Java. Плюс книга Портнякина: Swing, эффективные пользовательские интерфейсы, 2-е издание. Вот эта:
http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5774933/
К сожалению среди знакомых нет ни одного программиста или даже человека, на мнение которого можно было бы положиться. Поэтому вопрос к вам такой:
Что вы скажете насчет перечисленных мной книг? Может их стоит в другом порядке почитать? И что бы вы еще посоветовали почитать по java? 
Всем заранее спасибо за помощь!

**UPD:** Извиняюсь, действительно плохо искал, да и вопрос задал не корректно. [План изучения Java для Web](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/142472/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-java-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-web) Вот этот вопрос мне очень помог. И вот здесь тоже много полезного для себя нашел: [Подскажите книги по java ee](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/223886/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java-ee) Но если кто-нибудь еще что то интересное по java EE подскажет - буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Видимо глупый вопрос получился, раз такие негативные комментарии. Но я писал про final, finally и finalize вовсе не для того что бы похвастаться, прекрасно понимаю что хвастаться тут нечем. Я к тому, что почти во всех книгах, которые мне попадались: Шилдт, Хорстманн, Блох, Эйкель разжевываются именно такие вещи, снова и снова. Повторение конечно мать учения, но хочется уже и чего то другого. На java пишутся серверная часть веб приложений. Вот по этой теме очень мало информации нашел. Очень интересно именно что в этом направлении почитать

Comment: Больше практики. Книги без подкрепелния практикой - ничто. И постепенно меняй баланс с книг на практику, тогда будет толк.

Comment: @iksuy: В том то и дело что у меня почти одна практика) придумываю себе задания, например калькулятор, змейка, морской бой. И там естественно нужны и исключения и Generiks и файловый ввод-вывод и многопоточность. Дело в том что топчусь на одном месте. Пишу программы примерно одного уровня. Да и книги все об этом. Хочется работать с сетью на java, изучать JSP, JSF, Tomcat, Spring и т.д. Нигде такой литературы найти не могу. В том вопросе, который отмечен как дубликат тоже этого к сожалению нет.

Comment: Единой книги на все нету, главное - практика. Это отлично, что придумываешь задачи себе, чтобы использовать описанные технологии нужно ставить себе соответствующие задачи. Ясное дело, что делая змейку или калькулятор Spring не пригодится. Но можно ведь усовершенствовать задачу. Например тот же морской бой, его можно сделать сетевым, вот тебе и работа с сетью, далее можно реализовать его с помощью JSP в веб-браузере, или какой-нибудь игровой сервис, тут уж и Spring пригодится. По спрингу полно примеров с самого начального уровня, сам на них учился.

Comment: @iksuy: Спасибо, вы натолкнул меня на мысль) Но только что бы прикручивать к программе JSP, Spring, надо же о них где то почитать.. Можно вопрос, а как вы сами изучали эти технологии? Может это уже на работе изучают? Или по каким то ресурсам в интернете? Или по книгам?

Comment: По спрингу лично я читал Spring in Action, но это было уже после того, как я его стал активно использовать. Вот в этом вопросе накидали ссылок например: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/31795/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java-spring
Обычно я делаю так, если нужно познакомиться с чем-то незнакомым: открываю гугл, пишу, например "простое приложение spring" открываю ссылки, гляжу что мне больше по душе, и делаю. Потом добавляю всякую отсебятину и т.д.

Comment: @iksuy: Спасибо большое за развернутые ответы! Теперь мысли по этой теме намного лучше улеглись в голове.